# building up console parameters in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am working on a script that calls a program passing varying parameters.  I'd like to build up the parameters as a string, something like:

```
$parameters = "";
if ($condition2) {
    $parameters = $parameters + " /include:hi /exclude:low"
}

if ($condition2) {
    $parameters = $parameters + " /v"
}

.\MyCommand.exe $parameters
```

The problem is that I'm not really passing a single string parameter to MyCommand.exe, but rather the string contains multiple parameters that should be passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Invoke-Expression

```
$RunQuery=.\MyCommand.exe + ' ' + $parameters
iex $RunQuery
```

real test:

```
$VerLDAP='dsquery * "cn=schema,cn=configuration,'+([ADSI]"LDAP://rootDSE").rootDomainNamingContext+'" -scope base -attr objectVersion'
iex $VerLDAP
```